# Choose Vertical or Horizontal Menus with my application

Tags: ux-designer, lean-ux

[image]

Hi everyone, My application is having information architecture like image, I am deciding between horizontal navigation and vertical navigation. I feel using vertical navigation would be better in this case, However there are many people saying to use horizontal navigation.
What is the best option?

Comment: The right Sub menu 2.1 and 2.2 should be Sub menu 4.1 and 4.2, shouldn't they? What do you mean by "_deciding between horizontal navigation and vertical navigation_"? The sketch contains both: horizontal menu bar items and vertical menu items, which looks OK IMO.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I mean this is the information structure on my application. The horizontal menu will look like this with the dropdown, while the vertical menu selection is the left menu

Comment: Can you show an example of both horizontal and vertical?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little research on my project, I came to the conclusion that **horizontal navigation** is the best option.
Especially in cases of complex architecture and a large number of submenus.

If you look at all the major projects (Salesforce, Stocks market apss, Jira, etc.) you will notice that they all use vertical navigation.

I highly recommend you read Taras's article on this topic - https://uxdesign.cc/top-navigation-vs-side-navigation-wich-one-is-better-24aa5d835643

Comment: Thanks @AndriiD, I found the answer in the article you shared